# Custom MySQL Query for Post and Post Meta

Tags: query, post-meta, mysql

I have a custom table called "tags" that contains a `charity_id` that is a reference to a post ID ... I need to query the "tags" table to grab this `charity_id` and then pull in the post title and a few of the meta data.

Ideally, the end result would produce the following:

```
tags.serial_number, post.title, post_meta_data.post_title, post_meta_data.location_city, post_meta_data.location_state, post_meta_data.location_country
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a custom MySQL query when the WordPress function  get_post_custom($post_id) would do all the work for you once you have the $post_id. I am assuming your post_meta_data.* refers to data in the WordPress table and not a custom table of yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `JOIN` for that. Try it like this:

```
$wpdb->get_results("SELECT tags.*, $wpdb->posts.*, $wpdb->postmeta.*
              FROM tags
              INNER JOIN $wpdb->posts ON tags.charity_id = $wpdb->posts.ID
              INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON tags.charity_id = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
              WHERE tags.charity_id = $charity_id"
            );
```

Comment: @MagentaCuda You're right. I overlooked that. `get_results()` will solve that.

Answer (score 0):

[Wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) can solve the custom table problems.
But tag.charity_id has to be foreign key of the charity.ID